# I'm trying to collapse and close the nav element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to collapse and close the nav element with jQuery. I'm using rails 5 with gem coffee-rails and 4.2.2 gem jquery-rails, 4.3.1 but the animate option doesn't respond.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click', function() {
    var currentNavHeight = $('nav').height();
    if (currentNavHeight < 6) {
      var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
      $('nav').animate({
        'height': newNavHeight + 'px'
      }, 750);
    } else {
      $('nav').animate({
        'height': '0px'
      }, 750);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  padding: 50px 15px 20px 15px;
  background-color: #4b0a0c;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're not using jQuery's toggle() method?

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their guides are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. When dealing with jQuery, use their reference: https://api.jquery.com. Also the OP probably isn't using `toggle()` because it doesn't animate the element as their logic attempts. `slideToggle()` would be more appropriate